# using if else condition with null value after where

Tags: mysql, database, conditional-statements

```
select  tbc.ID,tbc.Booking_reference,
    concat(tbc.PickupDate , tbc.pickuptime) as PickupTime ,
    (select master_package 
         from Tblmasterpackage 
         where package_id =tbc.BookingType) as Booking,
    concat('Hello42 ', tbc.DeviceType) as Partner,concat( tbc.UserName , tbc.MobileNo ) as ClientName,
    tbc.DropArea as droparea,
    tbc.PickupArea as departure,
    tbc.`Status`
    from tblcabbooking tbc 
    inner join  tbldriver td
    on tbc.pickup=td.uid
    inner join Tblmasterpackage tmp
    on tmp.package_id=tbc.BookingType

where  tbc.Bookingdate >= FromDate  AND tbc.Bookingdate <= Todate

when IF CallerID is not null
    THEN
and tbc.MobileNo=CallerID
END IF

when IF book_ref is not null
THEN
    and tbc.Booking_reference=book_ref
END IF

when IF  vehicle_number is not null
THEN
    and td.VehicleRegistrationNo=vehicle_number
END IF

when IF vehicle_Driver is not null
THEN
    and td.FirstName=vehicle_Driver
END IF

when IF PartnerType='Android Booking'
then
  and tbc.DeviceType='ANDROID'
END IF

when IF PartnerType='Web Booking'
THEN
    and tbc.DeviceType='WEB'
END IF

when IF  PartnerType='Call Center Booking'
THEN
    and tbc.DeviceType='0'
END IF

when IF  PartnerType='All Booking'
THEN
END IF

order by ID desc limit limit_check,limite_off;
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: please clarify how to use with null value in using in where case

Comment: we make a query  with seven value field so in some cases some values are going to be null so how to handle  in where case for null value to make use in mysql procedure

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
        and (tbc.Mobileno=IFNULL(CallerID,tbc.MobileNo) or (CallerID = null tbc.Mobileno =null))

    and ( tbc.Booking_reference=IFNULL(book_ref, tbc.Booking_reference) or (book_ref=null  tbc.Booking_reference = null))

    and ( td.VehicleRegistrationNo=IFNULL(vehicle_number, td.VehicleRegistrationNo) or ( vehicle_number =null  td.VehicleRegistrationNo = null))

and ( td.FirstName=IFNULL(vehicle_Driver, td.FirstName) or ( vehicle_Driver = null  td.FirstName = null))

and ( (PartnerType='Android Booking' and tbc.DeviceType='ANDROID')  

or ( PartnerType='Web Booking' and tbc.DeviceType='WEB')

or ( PartnerType='Call Center Booking' and tbc.DeviceType='0')

or ( PartnerType='All Booking' and 1=1 )

)
```

Comment: i need if value of  Mobileno is null than this case is not considered and also it is same for all procedure varriable

Comment: or (CallerID is null tbc.Mobileno is null) this condition cover null record

Comment: so if we consider this then are you sure it will fetch all  data from respected tables if we send all the related all data to be null

Comment: Try to you. If any problem then tell me

Comment: i have got an error  while we create an procedure     SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'tbc.Mobileno is null)) and ( tbc.Booking_reference=IFNULL(book_ref, tbc.Booki' at line 16

Comment: above query on with line of where condition is all same

Comment: Change query now check it

Comment: that means we change all query